# reporting services - data set has no query but works... Where could the query be located?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, reporting-services

I was given a report today with a normal embedded  data set (dataset1) and data source (datasource1) but the data set query is just a number: '1411'. The previous programer manually entered fields (not calculated fields) into the field tab.

When I click RUN, it works.

**How is it populating the page without a proper query?**

-There is only 1 tablix called (table1.) It also is pointing to dataset1.

-In Report Properties there is no VB code.

-RDL XML: Under dataset1's tag:

```
<DataSourceName>datasource1</DataSourceName> 
<CommandText>=1411</CommandText>
```

I see no other SQL listed. Could there be something else on the server that's triggering it?

Answer (score 2):

What sort of data source is "datasource1"?

If it's an RDBMS, check if there is a stored procedure or function in the database with the name "1411".

In SQL Server for example you could conceivably have a stored procedure called [1411] that returned a data set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming we are talking RDL (Report Definition Language). You might open this report with your favorite text editor and look at the CommandText XML tag to find the associated query. Hope that helps.

Comment: hmmm in the RDL file, it still has this under dataset1 tag      <DataSourceName>datasource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>=1411</CommandText>